# Accessing functions of added web service

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, asmx

I have created my own `WebService` in VS 2010. My project is called `sampleWebService` and inside my project I have successfully added/connected to  another `WebService` this is called `practiceService`.

`sampleWebService` has just the basic Hello World auto generated code in it, however, `practiceService` has `Web Method Functions` that handle database calls such as `getFirstName, getLastName,...`

My question isn't how to extract the data really since I know you have to use either `JSON or SOAP`. I'm just wondering what I have to type into my code to be able to see the functions and methods that are in my added web reference `practiceService` so I can connect to them.

Or maybe this is accomplished by using `JSON or SOAP`

Right now my code for my `sampleWebService` page is just as is:

```
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class Service1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService


    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You have made the mistake of using the ASMX web service technology. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: See [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the proxy class that was generated when you added the web reference. Also when you create the object of practice service it will give you access to all the web methods exposed in that web service.

To access the web method you have to do something like

```
ServerName.WebServiceName CallWebService = 
        new ServerName.WebServiceName();
    String sGetValue = CallWebService.MethodName();
    Label1.Text = sGetValue;
```

Comment: Yeah it gives me access to the functions and methods and what not but how do I actually access them?

Comment: I believe you said in your initial question that you know how to access the methods. However I have updated my actual reply and have added some code.